# PHP Uploading a File to a folder (within apache)

Tags: php, image, apache, file, upload

Okay, I am trying to create a webpage where it uploads a photo to a folder in the Apache htdocs. And...well...it doesn't work... I have been searching everywhere for tutorials on this and the entire thing needs to be done in PHP (some HTML is also allowed [No flash]).

Here is what I have....

```
    <p>Browse For a File on your computer to upload it!</p>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_photos.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="250000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>


      <?PHP      

    if ($uploadedfile_size >250000)
    {$msg=$msg."Your uploaded file size is more than 250KB so please reduce the file size and then upload.<BR>";
    $file_upload="false";} 

    else{

    if (!($uploadedfile_type<>"image/jpeg" OR $userfile_type<>"image/tiff" OR $userfile_type<>"image/png"))
    {$msg=$msg."Your uploaded file must be of JPG, PNG, or tiff. Other file types are not allowed<BR>";  
    $file_upload="false";}

    }
      ?>

      <!--
    •enctype="multipart/form-data" - Necessary for our PHP file to function properly.
    •action="upload_photos.php" - The name of our PHP page that was created.
    •method="POST" - Informs the browser that we want to send information to the server using POST.
    •input type="hidden" name="MA... - Sets the maximum allowable file size, in bytes, that can be uploaded. This safety mechanism is easily bypassed and we will show a solid backup solution in PHP. We have set the max file size to 100KB in this example.
    •input name="uploadedfile" - uploadedfile is how we will access the file in our PHP script.

      -->

</form>

  </label>
</form>
```

Now it gets past this point, however once it gets to the other page (upload_photos.php) it says "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"

```
    <?php

/*
When the uploader.php file is executed, the uploaded file exists in a temporary storage area on the server. If the file is not moved to a different location it will be destroyed! To save our precious file we are going to need to make use of the $_FILES associative array. 

The $_FILES array is where PHP stores all the information about files. There are two elements of this array that we will need to understand for this example.
 •uploadedfile - uploadedfile is the reference we assigned in our HTML form. We will need this to tell the $_FILES array which file we want to play around with.
•$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] - name contains the original path of the user uploaded file.
•$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] - tmp_name contains the path to the temporary file that resides on the server. The file should exist on the server in a temporary directory with a temporary name.

*/

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);


/*
Now all we have to do is call the move_uploaded_file function and let PHP do its magic. The move_uploaded_file function needs to know 1) The path of the temporary file (check!) 2) The path where it is to be moved to (check!).
*/

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}


/*

If the upload is successful, then you will see the text "The file filename has been uploaded". This is because move_uploaded_file returns true if the file was moved, and false if it had a problem.

If there was a problem then the error message "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!" would be displayed.

*/

?>
```

Please help me, I have looked through it line by line and i don't know why it's doing it. It's possibly a syntax error or something. I am brand new to PHP so i don't doubt it. Anyway, thanks ahead of time.

Comment: change $target_path to full server path.

Comment: What are you relevant Apache settings? Apache can also impose limits on file uploads' types and sizes. And what does your Apache error log say?

Comment: "I am brand new to PHP" --- and it is a great chance to learn how to debug **your** code. No one will do that for you and that's your everyday job as a programmer

Comment: Check the folder write permission in your apache server. It should be 755 or 777. if not working then provide full target path. Eg: /home/<sitename>/upload/ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop a [PHPinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) file down, and check what Apache has for upload_max_filesize under CORE. This might be set too low.

In case you over-looked it, check the permissions on the target directory. Make sure the target directory is set to 775, or just [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) the target directory before you write to it.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

to:

```
$test=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path);

if($test) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    var_dump($test);
}
```

then let us know that var_dump returns

Comment: I will do that in a little bit. Right now my laptop is currently doing updates (of course) and i'll try that as soon as It's done. (I had just gotten the laptop not long ago so there are many Windows Updates)

Comment: okay, the only thing the var_dump is returning is "bool(false)" nothing more. and I also tried to change the $target_path to the full path...I will now try the chmod permissions as well